# Python command line doesn't run <<install>> command

Tags: python, github

I was trying to install a open-source GitHub repository and when i came across to install Python for first time, i didn't install with Microsoft Store because my laptop policies doesn't allow access to Microsoft services.

So I installed Python by their original page:
Pyhton version: 3.11.4

When I try to run the follow command:

```
pip install "datadm[cuda]"
```

It propmts this:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install "datadm[cuda]"
        ^^^^^^^
```

Someone knows what is going on?

I need to run the following:

```
pip install "datadm[cuda]"
```

Comment: `pip` is not a Python command. That's meant to be run in your shell, not in Python.

Comment: What you are trying to install ?